# Does Oracle 10g automatically escape double quotes in recordsets?

Tags: oracle, parsing, oracle10g, client, oracle9i

I am encountering an interesting issue with an application that was migrated from Oracle 9i to 10g.
Previously, we had a problem when a field contained double quotes since Oracle recordsets encapsulated fields in double quotes.

Example:
"field1"||"field2"||"field "Y" 3"||"field4"

Since the move to 10g, I believe that the Oracle client-side driver is parsing the double quotes and replacing them with `&quot;`

Unfortunately I don't have an old 9i environment to test my theory.

Have you seen similar behavior or can someone validate if my theory is true?

Comment: Double-quotes are used by Oracle to delimit the names of identifiers in a query, e.g. SELECT "EMPNO" FROM "EMP". That expression doesn't appear to be part of valid SQL. With extra spaces for clarity: "field1" || "field2" || "field " Y " 3" || "field4" - something's missing.

Comment: What I posted are the results of a query which are returned in a recordset to VB.

I am trying to determine if the driver is escaping double quotes.  I can't find any evidence of any my application code doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It's an estrange behavior. Can you check your [NLS_xx environment variables](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm)? Some NLS_xx variables can translate chars, for instance NLS_LANG can translate acutes from a latin charset on client to a us2ascii charset on server.

To be sure about what is going, try to [trace Net connections](http://www.juliandyke.com/Diagnostics/Trace/NetTrace.html). You'll see everything moving from a side to other. Be careful...